# l'm receiving a broken password reset link when using django.contrib .... reset email

Tags: django

```
from django.urls import path, NoReverseMatch
from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path, include

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('login.html', views.login2, name='login2'),
    path('register.html', views.register, name='register'),
    path('logoutUser', views.logoutUser, name='logoutUser'),
    path('music.html', views.music, name='music'),
    path('profile.html', views.profile, name='profile'),

    path('reset_password/', 
        auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name="password_reset.html"),
        name="reset_password"),
    path('reset_password_sent/', 
        auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name="password_reset_sent.html"), 
        name="password_reset_done"),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', 
        auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name="password_reset_form.html"), 
        name="password_reset_confirm"),
    path('reset_password_complete/', 
        auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name="password_reset_done.html"), 
        name="password_reset_complete"),

    path('oauth/', include('social_django.urls',namespace='social')),
]
```

so I'm using this default password reset in Django and l get to send the email and receive it but the problem is that the reset link that will redirect me to the form is broken the port is missing, and if l fix the port in the URL after l click it works and takes me to the password_reset_confirm

this is the reset link l receive

http://localhost/reset/MQ/ac5zx3-f826598ef65286489c632fd68ecb1175/

Comment: What's broken about it? You say the port is missing. If the port is important, you need to setup your site object to include the port. So your URL on the site object might become `localhost:8000` and then links from django will be generated to use that.

Comment: okay so already it runs on localhost:8000 but it's failing to pick that up when sending the link generated from django

Comment: Yeah, links are generated using the site objects, so you need to modify it.

Comment: okay let me try to modify it